# How to use both fetch() and fetchAll() in a PDO wrapper class?

Tags: php, pdo, fetch, fetchall

How can I alter my PDO wrapper class, so that if I expect a single row result with my query it uses fetch() and if it expects multiple results it uses fetchAll().

Right now, if I have only one result I still have to loop through the result array and that seem pretty unpracticable to me.

Query in the model:

```
public function doccEdit() {

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

    $this->result = $GLOBALS['db']->select("creditcards", "id = ?", $id);

    print_r($this->result);

}
```

In the wrapper class:

```
public function run($sql, $bind="") {
    $this->sql = trim($sql);
    $this->bind = $this->cleanup($bind);
    $this->error = "";

    try {
        $pdostmt = $this->prepare($this->sql);
        if($pdostmt->execute($this->bind) !== false) {
            if(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("select", "describe", "pragma")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
                return $pdostmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            elseif(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("delete", "insert", "update")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
                return $pdostmt->rowCount();
        }   
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();    
        $this->debug();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just always fetchall()? If there's only one row, you'll get one...

Comment: Because I thought I could avoid the loop. With fetchall I have to use a loop even when there is only one result.

Comment: what does mysql_real_escape_string to do here? do you format `"creditcards"` properly?

Answer (score 2):

**DON'T TRY to automate everything**

The less magic in your code, the easier support and less painful troubles.
Don't try to stuff all the logic into one single method. It's a class! You can create as many methods as you need.

When you need `rowCount()` - select it explicitly! It's not that hard.
But when you stumble upon this code after couple months, you will know what does this value mean.

When you need single row - use a method to get a single row. 
When you need many rows - use a method to get many rows.
It is simple and extremely unambiguous!

When you turn back to your code after 2 months, you will have **absolutely no idea**, what did you *expected*. So - **always write it explicitly.**

Here is an excerpt from my [mysqli wrapper class](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php) to give you an idea:

```
public function query()
{   
    return $this->rawQuery($this->prepareQuery(func_get_args()));
}
/**
 * Helper function to get scalar value right out of query and optional arguments
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $name = $db->getOne("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=1");
 * $name = $db->getOne("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=?i", $id);
 *
 * @param string $query - an SQL query with placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the query
 * @return string|FALSE either first column of the first row of resultset or FALSE if none found
 */
public function getOne()
{
    $query = $this->prepareQuery(func_get_args());
    if ($res = $this->rawQuery($query))
    {
        $row = $this->fetch($res);
        if (is_array($row)) {
            return reset($row);
        }
        $this->free($res);
    }
    return FALSE;
}

/**
 * Helper function to get single row right out of query and optional arguments
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $data = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1");
 * $data = $db->getOne("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?i", $id);
 *
 * @param string $query - an SQL query with placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the query
 * @return array|FALSE either associative array contains first row of resultset or FALSE if none found
 */
public function getRow()
{
    $query = $this->prepareQuery(func_get_args());
    if ($res = $this->rawQuery($query)) {
        $ret = $this->fetch($res);
        $this->free($res);
        return $ret;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

/**
 * Helper function to get single column right out of query and optional arguments
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $ids = $db->getCol("SELECT id FROM table WHERE cat=1");
 * $ids = $db->getCol("SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tagname = ?s", $tag);
 *
 * @param string $query - an SQL query with placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the query
 * @return array|FALSE either enumerated array of first fields of all rows of resultset or FALSE if none found
 */
public function getCol()
{
    $ret   = array();
    $query = $this->prepareQuery(func_get_args());
    if ( $res = $this->rawQuery($query) )
    {
        while($row = $this->fetch($res))
        {
            $ret[] = reset($row);
        }
        $this->free($res);
    }
    return $ret;
}

/**
 * Helper function to get all the rows of resultset right out of query and optional arguments
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table");
 * $data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ?i,?i", $start, $rows);
 *
 * @param string $query - an SQL query with placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the query
 * @return array enumerated 2d array contains the resultset. Empty if no rows found. 
 */
public function getAll()
{
    $ret   = array();
    $query = $this->prepareQuery(func_get_args());
    if ( $res = $this->rawQuery($query) )
    {
        while($row = $this->fetch($res))
        {
            $ret[] = $row;
        }
        $this->free($res);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Look - from the function name you can always tell which result to expect:

```
$name = $db->getOne('SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = ?i',$_GET['id']);
$data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM ?n WHERE mod=?s LIMIT ?i",$table,$mod,$limit);
```

Don't be fooled by such a pitfall like number of returned rows.
There could be honest one row in the resultset which you intend to populate with `fetchAll`. So, it will return single-dimensional array instead of multi-dimensional and you will have plenty of video effects on your page

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't mark an answer as accepted. I thought I'd answer you question. I found this while looking for the answer myself. I agree with "Your Common Sense" in that they should be two separate functions. However, in direct answer to your question, this is what I had (PDO example rather than mysqli):

```
function select($sql,$params=NULL,$fetchType=NULL){
    try{
        $qry = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $qry->execute($params);
        if($qry->rowCount() > 1){
            if($fetchType == 'OBJ'){//returns object
                $results = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            }elseif($fetchType == 'NUM'){//-numerical array
                $results = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            }else{//default - associative array
                $results = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
        }
        else{
            if($fetchType == 'OBJ'){//returns object
                $results = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            }elseif($fetchType == 'NUM'){//-numerical array
                $results = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            }else{//default - associative array
                $results = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
        }

        if($results){
            return $results;
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $err){
        $this->logError($err);
    }
}
```

However I found that if I queried all rows in a table but there was only one row in the table it would return a 1-d array instead of a 2-d array. My code to handle the result wouldn't work for both types of arrays. I could handle that each time but I found it just easier to, as stated above, separate them into different functions so if I knew there would be only one answer I could call the appropriate function. This is what I have now:

```
function select($sql,$params=NULL,$fetchType=NULL){
    try{
        $qry = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $qry->execute($params);

        if($fetchType == 'OBJ'){//returns object
            $results = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }elseif($fetchType == 'NUM'){//-numerical array
            $results = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        }else{//default - associative array
            $results = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        if($results){
            return $results;
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $err){
        $this->logError($err);
    }
}

function selectAll($sql,$params=NULL,$fetchType=NULL){
    try{
        $qry = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $qry->execute($params);

        if($fetchType == 'OBJ'){//returns object
            $results = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }elseif($fetchType == 'NUM'){//-numerical array
            $results = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        }else{//default - associative array
            $results = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        if($results){
            return $results;
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $err){
        $this->logError($err);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just can't stand so much repeated code. You definitely need to learn how to use functions.

Comment: Is there a way to save the name of a function in a variable? (swap "fetch" with "fetchAll")?

Comment: there is not a single reason to do that